# How can i calculate array data

Tags: python, numpy

My problem is

```
data = [[-10,-2,-10,2,3],[0,20,3,2,-10]]   
data = np.array(data)   
for i in range(0,data.shape[0]):   
   for j in range(0,data.shape[1]):    
        if data[i][j] >= 0:
             data[i][j] = data[i][j] * 1.02* data[i][j]    
        elif data[i][j] <0:    
             data[i][j] = data[i][j] * 1.98*data[i][j]    
        else:    
             data[i][j] = -999999999999999
```

I want faster than loop @

helpme..

Comment: Are you sure the code works? That `data` because of having different no. of elems would be of object dtype won't have two dimensions and as such won't have `data.shape[1]`.

Comment: This line also seems problematic: `data[i] = data[i][j] * 1.98*data[i][j]`. Don't you mean `data[i][j] = ...`?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the answer below?

Comment: modified  code... check me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is a better way, but using masks cuts execution time by half (at least on my laptop, using the timeit module)

```
import numpy as np

# as Divakar pointed out, number of elements should be the same in each row
data = np.asarray([[-10,-2,-10,2,3,4],[0,20,3,2,-10,4]], dtype=np.float)
mask = (data>=0)
mask2 = 1 - mask

# For ndarray, * is element-wise multiplication
data2 = np.square(data)*(mask*1.02 + mask2*1.98)

# Your loop for comparison
for i in range(0,data.shape[0]):   
   for j in range(0,data.shape[1]):    
        if data[i][j] >= 0:
             data[i][j] = data[i][j] * 1.02* data[i][j]    
        elif data[i][j] <0:    
             data[i][j] = data[i][j] * 1.98*data[i][j]    
        else:    
             data[i][j] = -999999999999999

# Output should be the same
print data2
print data
```